# UPDATE with INNER JOIN is not updating

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I'm trying to transfer the impact value from an old table (esp) to a new table (esm). Both table share similar structures:

```
esp
+--------+------+----------------------------
|codeNorm|impact|Other columns i dont care...
+--------+------+----------------------------

esm
+--------------+------+--------------------------------------
|codeMasterNorm|impact|Other different columns i dont care...
+--------------+------+--------------------------------------
```

First i created a SELECT query that brings only the records that have different impact between them (impact can be NULL):

```
SELECT esm.codeMasterNorm, esm.impact, esp.codeNorm, esp.impact FROM esm
INNER JOIN esp ON esp.codeNorm = esm.codeMasterNorm AND IFNULL(esp.impact, 0) <> IFNULL(esm.impact, 0);
```

This returned:

> 163 rows in set (0.75 sec)

Then i created the UPDATE/INNER JOIN query

```
UPDATE esm
INNER JOIN esp ON esp.codeNorm = esm.codeMasterNorm AND IFNULL(esp.impact, 0) <> IFNULL(esm.impact, 0)
SET esm.impact = esp.impact;
```

This returned:

> Query OK, 163 rows affected (1.35 sec) Rows matched: 163  Changed: 163
>   Warnings: 0

But when i re-run the SELECT query again, this return the same result:

> 163 rows in set (1.25 sec)

Any ideas of why is not updating the records?

Comment: I cannot replicate this result.

Comment: Are `esp.codeNorm` and `esm.codeMasterNorm` 1:1? If you have two `esp` records for each `esm` record (based on that field comparison), and the `esp` rows have different `impact` values, then you cannot (obviously) give the `esm` record both values. Check with `SELECT codeNorm FROM esp GROUP BY codeNorm HAVING COUNT(*) <> 1`; it will give you a list of the repeated codeNorm values.

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, that was the issue. Someone reinserted some values and remove de UNIQUE index in the table. Can you add the answer so i can mark it as valid and close the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing UPDATE JOIN queries; if the join is not 1:1, the source of assigned value is not defined.

In this particular case, while the join was technically 1:1 due to the a.x != b.x condition, the update created different join pairs. The 1:1 that was assumed without that condition was not true.